# Azure devops reposのgit再クローンについて

Tags: git

Azure devops reposにあるリモートリポジトリをgit クローンしたのちに、エラーの関係でそのクローンしたローカルリポジトリを削除しました。
その後、再クローンしようと同じURLを入れてもエラーになってしまいます。
調べていて.gitファイルの削除も関係あるような気もするのですが、.gitファイルの削除方法が分からず実行できていない状況です。
解決方法が分かる方、助けていただけないでしょうか？

---

.gitファイルを削除し、再クローンできました。作業場所を変えて試したところ上手くいき、ディレクトリ削除してもクローンできていなかったのは恐らくネット環境が原因のようでした。
回答いただいた方、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 今回、.gitディレクトリの削除より先にgitclone したディレクトリごと削除してしまったのですが
この場合再度クローン実行はできないでしょうか？

Comment: 再クローンのときにどのようなコマンドを実行して、どのようなエラーが出ましたか。具体的に、省略せずに書いてください。

Answer (score 1):

.git は、ファイルではなくディレクトリとして作成されているはずです。
git clone を実行したディレクトリ下に、.git ディレクトリが作成されます。
ただし、.git には、隠し属性がついているので、表示オプションを変更して確認してください。

.git ディレクトリが確認出来たら、それを普通のファイル操作で削除できます。